# Force Plugin Updates: "Update Failed: Plugin update failed." after update one plugin

Tags: plugins, updates, transient

I'm developing a plugin that needs to do some force update checks for other plugins that I host on my site with EDD, so I had this UI:

[image]

And when the user clicks on the **Update** button, it does an API request to my site and decide if there's a new version available for that plugin; if there is a new version, I save some plugin data in a transient.

After that, the user needs to go to the Plugins page, and with the data that we just saved in the transient, we obtain the package download and more information about the plugin using the **EDD_SL_Plugin_Updater** class and do a force update check by resetting the `update_plugins` site transient:

```
$modules_to_update = ! $this->update_plugins ? $this->current_modules->modules : $this->update_plugins;

array_walk( $modules_to_update, array( $this, 'check_plugins_updates' ) );

private function check_plugins_updates( $module_data, $module_name ) {
   $plugin_constants = parent::get_plugin_constants_values( $module_name );

   if ( $this->update_plugins ) {
      new WPB_EDD_SL_Plugin_Updater( $this->current_modules->api_url, $plugin_constants['basename'], $module_data );

            /**
             * Reset the "update_plugins" site transient,
             * so it can do a force check plugin update.
             *
             * This is extremely necessary, because WordPress check
             * plugins after hours or even minutes, sometimes.
             */
            set_site_transient( 'update_plugins', '' );

            return;
        }
  }
```

It's all good so far, we get the plugins updates (In this image, the user clicked on the Update button for both plugins):

[image]

Then, the user update one plugin, and updates it correctly, with no error. But, if the user tries to update another plugin, let's say **WP Bullet Assets Manager**, gets an error:

`Update Failed: Plugin update failed.`

And in the developers console says:

`The plugin is at the latest version.`

And this is the response for the AJAX update:

[image]

But if the user update, for example, Contact Form 7, updates it correctly.

Also, I have to use the `upgrader_process_complete` action hook to set up the `update_plugins` site transient again, if I don't do that, the other update disappears.

The good thing here is, if I refresh the plugins page after one plugin updated, the other plugin updates normally, because I still have the plugin data in the transient.

So, I'm stuck there.

Also, I checked the `update_plugins` transient content and notice that when all is working, it shows me this:

[image]

But after update one plugin, just shows me this:

[image]

You can check the transient content here:

The good one: https://www.unserialize.com/s/41cddcdd-bd49-9de9-330e-000062c8267b

The bad one: https://www.unserialize.com/s/364b6ebe-e29b-4fc8-4360-0000723d32b8

Does anyone have created something like I want to do? I will really appreciate it.

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue, so for those people who want to achieve the same thing about forcing updates using EDD, here's the solution (or at least worked for me):

First of all, when you update a plugin via the plugins page, it does via AJAX, so I had to read the `/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php` file, and inside of the `wp_ajax_update_plugin()` function found that was executing `wp_update_plugins()` function, so I realized that was overwriting the `update_plugins` site transient.

At this point, I thought my filters were executing but no, the thing is I was executing those filters inside of the `current_screen` action, and when the `wp_update_plugins()` function was called from `wp_ajax_update_plugin()`, it wasn't listen to them.

So I had to create new filters and execute them when my class is invoked.

And that's it, problem solved. Hope you can find this useful.

Comment: Hello! Could you let us know how you fixed it with the code?